# Why is the code not reaching the success function in Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

The code is doing it's job, it is submitting the form to the DB and redirecting as well but the code isn't reaching the success function, any help would be appreciated.

Toastr has also been imported properly.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type:form.method,
                url: form.action,
                data: new FormData(form),   
                success: function(data){
                    toastr.success("Success");
                    /*console.log('Done');
                    let obj = JSON.parse(res);
                    //console.log(res); 
                    //return false;                         
                    if (obj.status == 'success') {
                        toastr.success("Success");
                        //window.location.replace("{{URL('admin/calling-cards/edit')}}/"+obj.id);   
                    } else if (obj.status == 'error') {
                        toastr.error(obj.msg);
                    }*/
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: *"...and redirecting as well..."* What do you mean by that?

Comment: `jQuery.ajax` isn't fundamentally broken, if your server returns a success response (`2xx`), it **will** call that success function. So look at the network panel to see what response code it's returning instead. For instance, a redirect (like `301` or `302`) won't trigger `success` because, well, that's not a success code, that's a redirect code (which doesn't do anything useful here).

Comment: well as url: form.action, is there it redirects to the specified form action.

Comment: To add to the above, either the page redirect you mention is happening before the AJAX response is received (which is why redirecting AND using AJAX is a little odd) or alternatively, there's an error in your JS/AJAX and the form submission is not being blocked. In the latter case, open devtools and inspect the console to find the error that's raised.

Comment: @DebajyotiDas *"well as url: form.action, is there it redirects to the specified form action"* I don't think you mean "[redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)." All that `url: form.action` does is tell `ajax` what URL to use, nothing to do with redirection.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder by redirection i mean it is hitting the route and heading to a controller with the data.
The form tag: <form action="{{ route('admin.about_us_admin.update',$about_us->id) }}" method="post" id="product-form" >

Comment: @DebajyotiDas - Okay, good. That's not redirection. Just routing. So what did you find out from the network panel in devtools?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm facing this error: Uncaught TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.
    jQuery 4
        i
        At
        param
        ajax
    submitHandler http://localhost:8000/admin/about_us/edit/2:386
    jQuery 12
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/admin/about_us/edit/2:369
    jQuery 13
jquery.min.js:2:73381
    jQuery 4
    submitHandler http://localhost:8000/admin/about_us/edit/2:386
    jQuery 12
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/admin/about_us/edit/2:369
    jQuery 13

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The processData: false,contentType: false, made it work.

The working code:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type:form.method,
                url: form.action,
                data: new FormData(form),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false, 
                success: function(res){
                    console.log("sdfsdf");
                    alert("adfsdf");
                    toastr.success("Success");
                    /*console.log('Done');
                    let obj = JSON.parse(res);
                    //console.log(res); 
                    //return false;                         
                    if (obj.status == 'success') {
                        toastr.success("Success");
                        //window.location.replace("{{URL('admin/calling-cards/edit')}}/"+obj.id);   
                    } else if (obj.status == 'error') {
                        toastr.error(obj.msg);
                    }*/
                }
            })
        }
```